# Transient reflectivity of metals at infrared energies

Tags: optics, electrons, laser, metals, infrared-radiation

The transient reflectivity of metals in pump-probe configuration has been extensively studied but, to the best of my knowledge, with a pump energy lower or equal than the probe energy. I tried to find references about this to no avail.

Would somebody be able to provide a few reference articles or books about the transient reflectivity of metals (femto-, picosecond timescale) that address the configuration where the pump energy is higher than the probe energy? Specifically, I am interested in the transient reflectivity of gold (Au) over a range going from the mid-infrared to the near-infrared after interband excitation. Any hints would also be appreciated.

EDIT: References to the pump energy =< probe energy case.

1. Sun, C.-K., Vallée, F., Acioli, L. H., Ippen, E. P. & Fujimoto, J. G. Femtosecond-tunable measurement of electron thermalization in gold. Phys. Rev. B 50, 15337–15348 (1994).
2. Del Fatti, N. et al. Nonequilibrium electron dynamics in noble metals. Phys. Rev. B 61, 16956–16966 (2000).
3. Schoenlein, R. W., Lin, W. Z., Fujimoto, J. G. & Eesley, G. L. Femtosecond studies of nonequilibrium electronic processes in metals. Phys. Rev. Lett. 58, 1680–1683 (1987).
4. Hohlfeld, J. et al. Electron and lattice dynamics following optical excitation of metals. Chem. Phys. 251, 237–258 (2000).
5. Guo, C., Rodriguez, G. & Taylor, A. J. Ultrafast Dynamics of Electron Thermalization in Gold. Phys. Rev. Lett. 86, 1638–1641 (2001).